# GCC 4.1.2 compilation error for stl_vector.h

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error for STL files on GCC 4.1.2. And the same code works properly without any compilation errors on GCC 3.4.6.
I am including some built-in headers in my code that in turn include these STL files. Hence, I cannot modify the header files.

I compile it using the following:

```
gcc  -I/grid/0/gs/java/jdk64/current/include -I/grid/0/gs/java/jdk64/current/include/linux -I/grid/0/tmp/direct/include/ydmg/ ydmg.cpp -I/grid/0/tmp/direct/include/ -o libydmg.so
```

Do I need to include some other parameter while compiling?

Could the compiler version be the cause of this problem?

The error is as follows:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:157: error: expected type-specifier
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:157: error: expected `>'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:157: error: expected unqualified-id before â>â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:932: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:932: error: âbool ytl::std::operator==(int)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:932: error: âbool ytl::std::operator==(int)â must take exactly two arguments
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In function âbool ytl::std::operator==(int)â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:933: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:933: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:934: error: âequalâ is not a member of âytl::stdâ
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:949: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:949: error: âbool ytl::std::operator<(int)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:949: error: âbool ytl::std::operator<(int)â must take exactly two arguments
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In function âbool ytl::std::operator<(int)â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:950: error: âlexicographical_compareâ is not a member of âytl::stdâ
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:950: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:951: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:956: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:956: error: âbool ytl::std::operator!=(int)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:956: error: âbool ytl::std::operator!=(int)â must take exactly two arguments
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In function âbool ytl::std::operator!=(int)â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:957: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:957: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:962: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:962: error: âbool ytl::std::operator>(int)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:962: error: âbool ytl::std::operator>(int)â must take exactly two arguments
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In function âbool ytl::std::operator>(int)â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:963: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:963: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:968: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:968: error: âbool ytl::std::operator<=(int)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:968: error: âbool ytl::std::operator<=(int)â must take exactly two arguments
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In function âbool ytl::std::operator<=(int)â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:969: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:969: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:974: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:974: error: âbool ytl::std::operator>=(int)â must have an argument of class or enumerated type
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:974: error: âbool ytl::std::operator>=(int)â must take exactly two arguments
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: In function âbool ytl::std::operator>=(int)â:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:975: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:975: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h: At global scope:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: variable or field âswapâ declared void
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: âytl::std::swapâ declared as an âinlineâ variable
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: template declaration of âint ytl::std::swapâ
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: âvectorâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: expected primary-expression before â,â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: â__xâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: âvectorâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: expected primary-expression before â,â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: expected primary-expression before â>â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:980: error: â__yâ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_bvector.h:110: error: expected template-name before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_bvector.h:110: error: expected `{' before â<â token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_bvector.h:110: error: expected unqualified-id before â<â token
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Here is the C++ code.
I am calling the methods from ydmg and yut libraries using JNI.
This code is working perfectly fine on gcc 3.4.6. Its gives errors on gcc 4.1.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ydmg/bd.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include "yut/string.h"
extern "C" int getAge();

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ydmgBd_getAge(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{

        ydmgBd bdObject;
        yutString s = bdObject.getKeys();
        printf("\ngetKeys() returns the key as : %s",s.c_str());

        yutHash user;
        yutString value = "abc";
        yutString key ="login";
        user.set(key,value);

        ydmgBd bd1(user);
        bool val = bd1.save(user);

        if(val){
                printf("\ntrue");
        }else {
                printf("\nfalse");
        }

        int age = bd1.getAge();

        printf("\nAge : %d ",age);
        printf("\nhi");

        return 1;
}

int main(){
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `g++` instead of `gcc` for .cpp source?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: (a) No, with .cpp extension GCC will work properly; (b) a C compiler would not talk about "must have an argument of class or enumerated type" in its errors

Comment: Show us how you're `#include`ing `vector`. It thinks you're in some namespace `ytl` for some reason.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: You are right... you will get more of `undefined reference` & other *cryptic* errors. 
@Garshita: Some code snippets?

Comment: While 4.1 is medieval, 3.4 is ancient, and it is likely that something has changed and the code is not standards compliant (and without seeing it, we can't tell). Also, you should think about trying a modern compiler, we are currently at 4.6

Comment: These sorts of errors sometimes occur when you leave a closing brace off a namespace in a header somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile cpp code with `gcc` and not with `g++`, you must link with `-lstdc++`, so that option is definitely missing.

However, the problem already occurs at the parsing step, so my suggestion is to check the namespaces... e.g. have a look at the error output:

```
...
    ytl::std::operator!=
...
```

`std` should not be in your personal `ytl` namespace. You are doing something wrong with your includes.

Comment: -lstdc++ is necessary anyway. The errors come from your includes. Please post some code that shows how and where you include your headers, and some example from the headers themselves.
Also, are you sure that your precompiled headers are correct?

Answer (score 1):

One of your header files is almost certainly including:

```
#include <vector>
```

Before that line, add:

```
#undef max
```

And I believe your compiles will start working.  This is happening b/c you are also using the C std library, which for some functions uses macros, and in this case, causes the preprocessor to freak out.  I've seen this same error on Linux, and undefining that symbol was all i needed to get things compiling again.